# Dishwasher mid-cycle manual fill - possible?

Tags: water, dishwasher

I tried a serach but couldn't find a suitable answer, hoping someone here can help.
So, in short our dishwasher was put on last night without the water supply on, noticed it after maybe 5 minutes, so immediately turned it off.  Trying to resolve this, I've pushed some buttons, but can't change the cycle or select a new cycle, to start a fresh wash (with the water supply on this time!).
So, it's stuck mid-cycle, can I just put water in the front/main door and then leet it carry on with it's cycle?
It's an older model, about 12 years old and is a Diplomat ACA 9202, so not a very well known or expennsive brand.

Comment: Have you put the water supply on? Usually they will continue once they have water. If you have pushed loads of buttons you may have to find the combination of buttons that does a reset.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Is there a reason you don't just turn it on and let it complete the cycle? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the responses, The water supply was switched on when we noticed what we'd done, however, I guess it had already gone through the "fill with water" cycle, as it wasn't pumping anymore water into it.  I have the manual and there doesn't seem to be a complete "reset" option that I can find.  We've also disconnected it from any power supply for over 24 hours but that doesn't seem to have reset the cycle either. With the comment above about them continue once they have water, that's what made me ask if I could manually fill it then let it continue it's cycle?  Thanks all for the help

Comment: To close this off and say thanks for the help, an update.  I filled the dishwasher with as much water as I could last night, from the front/main door.  I took 6 litres before it started to get to close to overflowing all over the kitchen.  I then shut the door and let it do it's thing and finish teh cycle, for some reason the cycle finished very quickly, I don't know why.  Anyway, after all that the dishwasher is now fine and working again no problem.  Not saying this will work for anyone else, just that it got me passed the stuck cycle I was in.  Thanks again all.  Ash

Answer (score 1):

Most dishwashers have a "cancel" option to end the current cycle and start over. Consult the manual, perhaps? Unfortunately what I've been able to find for "online" manuals for this model appear to be from very sketchy sites that don't load, perhaps you have a paper version that's 12 years old?

If no luck there:

Try turning the circuit breaker feeding it off for a minute or more.

Comment: Hi, there doesn't appear to be a cancel option that will work, I've tried to re-program it, but I think in my initial panic of pushing loads of buttons on random order it now seems stuc and I can't select a different program.  I know, it's my own fault, could kick myself.

Comment: To close this off and say thanks for the help, an update.  I filled the dishwasher with as much water as I could last night, from the front/main door.  I took 6 litres before it started to get to close to overflowing all over the kitchen.  I then shut the door and let it do it's thing and finish the cycle, for some reason the cycle finished very quickly, I don't know why.  Anyway, after all that the dishwasher is now fine and working again no problem.  Not saying this will work for anyone else, just that it got me passed the stuck cycle I was in.  Thanks again.  Ash